# Format linetype based on 2 conditions ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, line

I'm plotting values based on a reciprocal transplant (origin -> new, origin -> origin) for 2 sites. I want to format the linetype for these values based on history where origin -> origin is a solid line, but origin -> new is a dashed line. With 2 sites, the values for "origin" and "new" are different. Below is a subset of the data:

```
structure(list(FragID = c("1004", "1006", "1015", "1038", "1087", 
"1089", "1107", "1116"), ParentID = c("166", "166", "166", "166", 
"144", "144", "144", "144"), ParentSite.x = c("Inner Bay", "Inner 
Bay", "Inner Bay", "Inner Bay", "Outer Bay", "Outer Bay", "Outer 
Bay", "Outer Bay"), FragSite.x = c("Inner Bay", "Outer Bay", "Inner 
Bay", "Outer Bay", "Inner Bay", "Inner Bay", "Outer Bay", "Outer 
Bay"), TotalSA = c(0.0171970755726674, 0.0338197513082082, 
0.0215722601402604, 0.030712272182997, 0.027529366126288, 
0.029650482611575, 0.0316984120058258, 0.0356299659679559), T03SA = 
c(0.000709604810935872, 0.00148788795124323, 0.00109901406229665, 
0.000966259734683879, 0.000701528253168926, 0.000828107993427705, 
0.00079488114602085, 0.000904344998291552)), .Names = c("FragID", 
"ParentID", "ParentSite.x", "FragSite.x", "TotalSA", "T03SA"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 21L, 22L, 28L, 
29L))
```

What I want is for Inner Bay -> Inner Bay and Outer Bay -> Outer Bay to be solid lines and Inner Bay -> Outer Bay and Outer Bay -> Inner Bay to be dashed. What I have so far is below:

```
GPBWM03 = ggplot(M3, aes(x = TotalSA, y = T03SA, 
                 group = interaction(FragSite.x, ParentSite.x), color = FragSite.x, 
                 linetype = ParentSite.x)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5, stroke = 0) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y~x, se = FALSE, fullrange = 
TRUE) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Inner Bay" = "coral2", 
"Outer Bay" = "skyblue4"))
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but I think what you want is to just add a variable that states that either that observation is within groups (inner to inner or outer to outer) or between groups (inner to outer or outer to inner). You can add that and then assign linetype to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
ggplot(M3,
       aes(
           x = TotalSA,
           y = T03SA,
           color = FragSite.x,
           linetype = interaction(ParentSite.x, FragSite.x)
       )) +
    geom_smooth(
        method = "lm",
        formula = y ~ x,
        se = FALSE,
        fullrange =
            TRUE
    ) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1, 2, 2, 1)) +
    scale_color_manual(values =
                           c("Inner Bay" = "coral2", "Outer Bay" = "skyblue4"))
```

To get an output like:

[image]

This was made using the dataset below, as there were line breaks in some of the values in your original `dput` output above:

```
structure(list(FragID = c("1004", "1006", "1015", "1038", "1087", 
"1089", "1107", "1116"), ParentID = c("166", "166", "166", "166", 
"144", "144", "144", "144"), ParentSite.x = c("Inner Bay", "Inner Bay", 
"Inner Bay", "Inner Bay", "Outer Bay", "Outer Bay", "Outer Bay", 
"Outer Bay"), FragSite.x = c("Inner Bay", "Outer Bay", "Inner Bay", 
"Outer Bay", "Inner Bay", "Inner Bay", "Outer Bay", "Outer Bay"
), TotalSA = c(0.0171970755726674, 0.0338197513082082, 0.0215722601402604, 
0.030712272182997, 0.027529366126288, 0.029650482611575, 0.0316984120058258, 
0.0356299659679559), T03SA = c(0.000709604810935872, 0.00148788795124323, 
0.00109901406229665, 0.000966259734683879, 0.000701528253168926, 
0.000828107993427705, 0.00079488114602085, 0.000904344998291552
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 21L, 
22L, 28L, 29L))
```

**Edit:** For combined legend, it may be easiest to just manually assign the colors in addition to the linetypes:

```
ggplot(M3,
       aes(
           x = TotalSA,
           y = T03SA,
           color = interaction(ParentSite.x, FragSite.x),
           linetype = interaction(ParentSite.x, FragSite.x)
       )) +
    geom_smooth(
        method = "lm",
        formula = y ~ x,
        se = FALSE,
        fullrange =
            TRUE
    ) +
    scale_linetype_manual(name = "Combination", values = c(1, 2, 2, 1)) +
    scale_color_manual(name = "Combination", values = c("coral2", "coral2", "skyblue4", "skyblue4"))
```

Output:

[image]

Alternatively, you may find it easier to create an interaction variable as suggested by some of the other answers here.

Comment: How do I format the legend so it's a single legend displaying both color and linetype? So combining the 2 legends into a single one.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to create an additional variable that codes the `linetype`. The effect is that you get a legend that show the two factors indedendetly:

```
M3 <- structure(list(FragID = c("1004", "1006", "1015", "1038", "1087", "1089", "1107", "1116"), 
                     ParentID = c("166", "166", "166", "166", "144", "144", "144", "144"), 
                     ParentSite.x = c("Inner Bay", "Inner Bay", "Inner Bay", "Inner Bay", "Outer Bay", "Outer Bay", "Outer Bay", "Outer Bay"), 
                     FragSite.x = c("Inner Bay", "Outer Bay", "Inner Bay", "Outer Bay", "Inner Bay", "Inner Bay", "Outer Bay", "Outer Bay"), 
                     TotalSA = c(0.0171970755726674, 0.0338197513082082, 0.0215722601402604, 0.030712272182997, 0.027529366126288, 0.029650482611575, 0.0316984120058258, 0.0356299659679559), 
                     T03SA = c(0.000709604810935872, 0.00148788795124323, 0.00109901406229665, 0.000966259734683879, 0.000701528253168926, 0.000828107993427705, 0.00079488114602085, 0.000904344998291552)), 
                     .Names = c("FragID", "ParentID", "ParentSite.x", "FragSite.x", "TotalSA", "T03SA"), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 21L, 22L, 28L, 29L))
M3$in.out <- interaction(M3$ParentSite.x, M3$FragSite.x)
M3$comb <- 'same'
M3$comb[which(M3$ParentSite.x!=M3$FragSite.x)] <- 'different'
GPBWM03 = ggplot(M3, aes(x = TotalSA, y = T03SA, 
                         group = interaction(FragSite.x, ParentSite.x), color = FragSite.x, 
                         linetype = comb)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5, stroke = 0) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y~x, se = FALSE, fullrange = 
                TRUE) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Inner Bay" = "coral2", 
                                "Outer Bay" = "skyblue4"))
GPBWM03
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `dput` had an incorrect format. I manually created it using the following:

```
df <- data.frame(FragID = c("1004", "1006", "1015", "1038", "1087", "1089", "1107", "1116"),
                 ParentID = c("166", "166", "166", "166", "144", "144", "144", "144"),
                 ParentSite.x = c("Inner Bay", "Inner Bay", "Inner Bay", "Inner Bay", "Outer Bay", "Outer Bay", "Outer Bay", "Outer Bay"),
                 FragSite.x = c("Inner Bay", "Outer Bay", "Inner Bay", "Outer Bay", "Inner Bay", "Inner Bay", "Outer Bay", "Outer Bay"),
                 TotalSA = c(0.0171970755726674, 0.0338197513082082, 0.0215722601402604, 0.030712272182997, 0.027529366126288, 0.029650482611575, 0.0316984120058258, 0.0356299659679559),
                 T03SA = c(0.000709604810935872, 0.00148788795124323, 0.00109901406229665, 0.000966259734683879, 0.000701528253168926, 0.000828107993427705, 0.00079488114602085, 0.000904344998291552))
```

Then, I added a new column to your data which determines the line type based on the interaction of `ParentSite.x` and `FragSite.x` using the `tidyverse` package:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(linetype = ifelse(ParentSite.x=='Inner Bay'&FragSite.x=='Inner Bay' | ParentSite.x=='Outer Bay'&FragSite.x=='Outer Bay'
                             , 'Matching', 'Not Matching'))
```

Then, we plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = TotalSA, y = T03SA, color = FragSite.x, linetype = linetype)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5, stroke = 0) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y~x, se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Inner Bay" = "coral2", 
                                "Outer Bay" = "skyblue4")) +
  labs(linetype='Line Type')
```

[image]